# How can I prevent the Media Centre Extender from recreating port rules?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, windows-firewall, ports

I have a windows 10 PC which hosts a web service for an application, so there is a port rule for it to come through 7778. Recently a rule is overwriting the web service one causing it to stop working, it's name is "Media Center Extenders - WMDRM-ND/RTP/RTCP (UDP-In)". This has been deleted and replaced but recently it came back again, I suspect after an update.

I'm struggling to find anything online on how to stop it, I don't think I need the media centre extender at all as the laptop is only used to host a single application. I do not have remote access to the PC in question so the simpler the solution the better, I will have to relay it to someone without a technical background.

I unfortunately can't just move the port for the web service due to reasons out of my control. I also tried looking in services but there is nothing there to disable.

Comment: Since the only thing this device does is host an application.  Are you opposed to performing a Reset or using "Fresh Start" in order to reinstall Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound Not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has removed Windows Media Center from Windows 10, so it's weird
that you have it installed, unless that was done manually using the
[unofficial installer](https://www.howtogeek.com/258695/how-to-install-windows-media-center-on-windows-10/).

See the article
[How to Disable (Uninstall and Remove) Windows Media Center](https://techjourney.net/how-to-disable-uninstall-and-remove-windows-media-center/)
for a list of three methods to disable the Media Center.
I don't know how Media Center was installed so cannot say which one will be
effective.
In your situation, the easiest one might be in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd)
to run the command:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsMediaCenter /v MediaCenter /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: tried the services method before and there was nothing there, it's like the media centre was removed but the rules left over somehow. Will run the command and see if it prevents it happening again